# Adonis.js : E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: Route not found POST /posts/add

Tags: adonis.js

I just started learning Adonis.js. I am following a tutorial.

I am trying to save data to the database. Here is the code I have

> Add.edge

```
@layout('main')

@section('content')
    <a href="/posts">Go back</a>
    <hr>
    <h1>Add Post</h1>
    <form actions="/posts" method="POST">
        {{csrffield}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"  placeholder="title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Body</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="body" class="form-control"  placeholder="body">
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
```

> Route.js

```
Route.on('/').render('home')
Route.get('/posts', 'PostController.index')
Route.get('/posts/add', 'PostController.add')
Route.get('/posts/:id', 'PostController.details')
Route.post('/posts', 'PostController.store')
```

> PostController

```
class PostController {
    async add ({ view }) {
        return view.render('posts.add')

    }

    async store({ request, response, session }) {
        const post = new Post();

        post.title = request.input('title')
        post.body = request.input('body')

        await post.save()

        session.flash({ notification: 'Post Added!' })

        return response.redirect('/posts')
    }
```

When I submit the form, it gave an error

> E_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: Route not found POST /posts/add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My route is supposed to be like this

```
Route.post('/posts/add', 'PostController.store').as('post.store')
```